# Kong 2.6.0: Which versions of Postgres are supported?

Tags: postgresql, kong, kong-ingress

I'm currently using `Kong 2.6.0` and I need to know which versions of Postgres are supported by this version of Kong. I've checked the Kong documentation, but I couldn't find a clear answer.

Can someone please tell me which versions of Postgres are compatible with `Kong 2.6.0`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no issue with using Kong with any PostgreSQL version above 9.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PostgreSQL 16. Information for Kong 2.8, you can apply for Kong 2.6

[image]

See https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/support/third-party/